# How to make an electronic queue for bank visitors on django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, automation

I would like to make an electronic queue for bank visitors. When the client comes to the bank, he presses the button, then the terminal prints out the number. And I want to do it on django. Please advise what useful libraries are there in python django? Ideas will also be helpful.

Comment: in view.py create a global counter variable. when client clicks the button then view will be call. add logic to increase global counter and return global counter value as response. untill your server get restarts your counter value will be updating constantly.

Comment: But I have n number of cashiers, I need to distribute the queue to these cashiers. Can't find a solution for this

Comment: just built api and make call to api on push of button and increase counter